# How can I deploy a flask app on Lightsail with crash protection?

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, flask, web, amazon-lightsail

I am looking for help deploying my flash app. I've already written the app and it works well. I'm currently using the following command in the directory of my flask code:

`sudo uwsgi --socket 0.0.0.0:70 --protocol=http -w AppName:app --buffer-size=32768`

This is on my Amazon Lightsail instance. I have the instance linked to a static public IP, and if I navigate to the website, it works great. However, to get the command to continuously run in the background even after logging out of the Lightsail, I first start a `screen` command, execute the above line of code, and then detach the screen using `ctrl-a-d`.

The problem is, if the app crashes (which is understandable since it is very large and under development), or if the command is left running for too long, the process is killed, and it is no longer being served.

I am looking for a better method of deploying a flask app on Amazon Lightsail so that it will redeploy the app in the event of a crash without any interaction from myself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Generally you would write your own `unit` file for `systemd` to keep your application running, auto restart when it crashes and start when you boot your instances.

There are **many tutorials** out there showing how to write such a `unit` file. Some examples:

- [Systemd: Service File Examples](https://www.shellhacks.com/systemd-service-file-example/)
- [Creating a Linux service with systemd](https://medium.com/@benmorel/creating-a-linux-service-with-systemd-611b5c8b91d6)
- [How to write startup script for Systemd?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/47695/how-to-write-startup-script-for-systemd)

Comment: I see, so you're saying continue to use the uwsgi method, but instead of the poor work-around of `screen`, instead make it a monitored system process using `unit` and `systemd`?

Comment: @jake9115 Yes, that's how it is normally done. For example Elastic Beanstalk runs your applications this way. Obviously the details of how to write a unit file to suit your exact needs is a very specific task, thus its difficult to provide for me more detailed answer. You could also use `nohup` instead of `screen` as a quick workaround, but it is less powerful then writing your own unit file and using `systemd`.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [pm2](https://pm2.keymetrics.io/docs/usage/quick-start/)

> Starting an application with PM2 is straightforward. It will auto
> discover the interpreter to run your application depending on the
> script extension. This can be configurable via the Ecosystem config
> file, as I will show you later on this article.

All you need to install pm2 and then

```
pm2 start appy.py
```

> Great, this application will now run **forever**, meaning that **if the process exit or throw an exception it will get automatically restarted**. If you exit the console and connect again you will still be able to check the application state.

To list application managed by PM2 run:

```
pm2 ls
```

You can also check logs

```
pm2 logs
```

**Keeping Processes Alive at Server Reboot**

> If you want to keep your application online across unexpected (or expected) server restart, you will want to setup init script to tell your system to boot PM2 and your applications.

It’s really simple with PM2, just run this command (without sudo):

```
pm2 startup
```

[Pm2 Manage-Python-Processes](https://blog.pm2.io/2018-09-19/Manage-Python-Processes/)